# Trying to get the HTML displayed to change every time a new button is clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
let table = 6;
let i = 1;
$(function() {
    let $newOperatorButton = $('button');
       
    $newOperatorButton.on('click', function math(){
            let msgOperator = '';
            let expression;
            let operator = $(this).attr("value");
            if(operator === '+'){
                msgOperator = ' + ';
                expression = (table + i);
                while(i < 11){
                    msg += table + msgOperator + i + ' = ' + (table + i) + '<br />';
                    i++; 
                }
            } else if (operator === '-') {
                msgOperator = ' - ';
                expression = (table - i);
                while(i < 11){
                    msg += table + msgOperator + i + ' = ' + (table - i) + '<br />';
                    i++; 
                }
```

some code missing but it adds multiplication and division

```
            let el = document.getElementById('blackboard');
            el.innerHTML = msg;
        
        }
    );
});
```

This code is inside the body tag in my index.html

```
        <section id="page">
            <section id="blackboard"></section>
        </section>
        <form id="operator">
            <button name="add" type="button" value="+">+</button>
            <button name="subtract" type="button" value="-">-</button>
            <button name="multiply" type="button" value="x">x</button>
            <button name="division" type="button" value="/">/</button>
        </form>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/index.js"></script>
```

I have it so it prints out a table with 10 numbers depending on the button clicked. For ex. table = 6 and i = 1 is  6+1=7.... 6+10=16

Answer (score 0):

You need an if statement at the end that reset your equations and variables.

after you've run your equation "i" is still equal to 11 so it never passes into the while loops again, you also need to empty your message so it doesn't keep adding addition text to your existing text.

```
 $("#blackboard").html(msg)
         
        if (i == 11) {
            
            i = 1
            msg = ""
            
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for that!